# how can I extract group of my users in facebook apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, extract, usergroups

how can I extract users in one of my groups from within a facebook app?

I wrote

`$userData = $facebook->api('/group');`

but I did not receive anything! just an empty array.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) which explains the [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) you need from the user. In addition, both [users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and [pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) have the `group` connection which can be called as such `graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/group?access_token=...`